# Unit testing dilemma

Tags: java, unit-testing, tdd, mockito, guice

I am working on a class which stored some session information to communicate with the third party APIs. So, basically it has lots of behavior and little states to maintain. Here is one of its method:

```
  public LineItem getLineItem(
      String networkId, String lineItemId) throws ApiException_Exception {
    LineItem lineItem = null;
    session.setCode(networkId); 
    LineItemServiceInterface lineItemService = servicesInterface.lineItemService(session);
    StatementBuilder statementBuilder =
        new StatementBuilder()
            .where("id = " + lineItemId.trim())
            .orderBy("id ASC")
            .limit(StatementBuilder.SUGGESTED_PAGE_LIMIT);
    LineItemPage lineItemPage =
        lineItemService.getLineItemsByStatement(statementBuilder.toStatement());
    if (lineItemPage != null && lineItemPage.getResults() != null) {
      lineItem = lineItemPage.getResults().get(0);
    }
    return lineItem;
  }
```

I am stuck on how to test this method, it has too many implicit dependencies on the third party objects. The objects are difficult to create on own. Other big issue is that `getLineItemByStatement` does a network call(SOAP) behind the scene.

On my side I am trying to mock the external service and checking if the service is requesting the data with correct `Statement` apart from that I am not able to do anything since I have no state change in my object and most of the object interacting are third party.

**Question**

Most of confusion in these scenario is to how much my class should know about the collaborators? How much my test need to know about the about the objects use by my method under test?

example:

```
  @Test
  public void shouldGetLineItem() throws ApiException_Exception {
    when(servicesInterface.lineItemService(dfpSession)).thenReturn(mockLineItemService);
    dfpClient.getLineItem("123", "123");
    Statement mockStatement = mock(Statement.class);
    Statement statement =
        new StatementBuilder()
            .where("id = 123")
            .orderBy("id ASC")
            .limit(StatementBuilder.SUGGESTED_PAGE_LIMIT)
            .toStatement();

    verify(dfpSession).setNetworkCode("123");
    verify(mockLineItemService).getLineItemsByStatement(isA(Statement.class));
  }
```

As we can see my test knows too much about my method under test.

**Update 1**

After some time I see that its become too difficult to unit test my classes because the refernce to `LineItem` is scattered everywhere and since `LineItem` has many deep linking to other objects and difficult to create my own hence, I have decided to create a domain model which contains the relevant details for my application.

```
  public LineItemDescription getLineItem(String networkId, String lineItemId)
      throws ApiException_Exception {
    dfpSession.setNetworkCode(networkId);
    LineItemServiceInterface lineItemService = servicesInterface.lineItemService(dfpSession);
    return buildLineItemDescription(
        getFirstItemFromPage(lineItemService.getLineItemsByStatement(buildStatement(lineItemId))));
  }
```

Comment: Mocking looks like the right answer to me. What is the concrete problem?

Comment: @JBNizet updated with question and unit test at present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Basic Approach**

This looks like a case where I considere Unittesting of limited value. It seems that what you really want might be a test, that ensures that the SOAP service gets called properly, and the results get converted as required. So I would go for an integration test. The test will call the/a SOAP service, but I would mock it. I.e. you set a up a service where you can specify how it will react on your request. Then you call the method, and check the result.

**Other stuff to consider**
I assume that you already tested all the stuff used in that method, using unit test.

One thing that is confusing to the reader of the code and which might make testing harder then it need to be is the somewhat strange handling of the `networkid`. It gets set in the `session` as the 'Code' which in itself is strange, but it doesn't get used. Well actually I assume something is picking up that value from the session, but this is basically global state and makes it rather hard to reason about what is going on. If you need it in the global state to avoid passing it around all over the place, move that part out in a separate method (or extract the rest in a new method), so you can test everything else, without the change of global state. Or pass it explitely to the methods, that actually need it.

Comment: After setting code, in the next line `session` object is passed to get the `lineItem` service so, basically `lineItem` service depends on the session. Since its how the third party API is designed I can't do much to refactor it.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by refactoring the method (just by extracting private methods and moving things around) to look something like this:

```
public LineItem getLineItem(String networkId, String lineItemId) throws ApiException_Exception {
    LineItemServiceInterface lineItemService = getLineItemServiceForNetwork(networkId);
    return getFirstItemFromPage(lineItemService.getLineItemsByStatement(buildStatement(lineItemId)));
}
```

Looking at this version of the code, we see that this method has at least one too many responsibilities.  For example, creating and setting up the `LineItemServiceInterface` should be offloaded to a collaborator that can be mocked, or maybe it should be provided by the caller instead of the `networkId` (since if the caller doesn't provide the service you have to mock the service provider collaborator to return another mock). If it's too painful (because of lots of legacy dependancies) to offload the creation of the `LineItemServiceInterface` to another class, a quick and dirty alternative would be to make `getLineItemServiceInterface()` protected or package level and override it to return a mock in a subclass that you use for the test.

So for the "normal usage" case your test of this method needs to 1) stub (using `Mockito.when()`) that when the mocked service interface receives a correctly formed statement with the given `lineItemId`, it returns a list containing one `LineItem` instance and then 2) check that the `LineItem` instance in question is returned by `getLineItem()`. Then you know that `getLineItem()` correctly calls the service and correctly extracts the result.

BTW, you don't need to mock a `Statement`. You need to write a [matcher](https://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.7/javadoc/org/mockito/Matchers.html) which verifies that the `Statement` instance passed to `getLineItemsByStatement()` is correctly formulated with the right ID value, ordering and limit.  If `Statement` is a 3rd-party class which does not allow access to such info (either directly via getters or indirectly via generated query code), you might consider offloading the `Statement` creation to another injected collaborator, which you would mock for this test, and then you verify that collaborator elsewhere using an integration test against a real service.

EDIT: based on comments, here's a rough example of the test to write, assuming further refactoring to offload `LineItemServiceInterface` setup a collaborator:

```
@Test
  public void shouldGetLineItem() throws ApiException_Exception {
    when(lineItemserviceProviderMock.getLineItemService(NETWORK_ID, dfpSession)).thenReturn(mockLineItemService);     
    when(mockLineItemService.getLineItemsByStatement(argThat(statementMatcher)).thenReturn(LIST_WITH_EXPECTED_LINE_ITEM);
    LineItem expectedResult = dfpClient.getLineItem(NETWORK_ID, LINE_ITEM_ID);
    assertEquals(EXPECTED_LINE_ITEM, expectedResult);
  }
```

The variable `statementMatcher` in the test would look roughly like this:

```
   ArgumentMatcher<Statement> statementMatcher = new ArgumentMatcher<Statement>{
      public boolean matches(Object stmt) {
          return queryMatches(((Statement)stmt).getQuery()) && valuesMatch(((Statement)stmt).getValues());
      }

      private boolean queryMatches(String query) {
        return EXPECTED_QUERY.equals(query);
      }

      private boolean valuesMatch(String_ValueMapEntry[] values) {
        // TODO: verify values here 
      }
   }
```

Comment: `servicesInterface` does exactly what you are saying. I have encapsulated the original service creation inside my collaborator class, also you can see in my test that I have mocked that service too so, we are on the same page on this issue. Second, I agree that we can further make private methods but how do we test them then? or how to stub their return value?

Comment: Also `seesion` is a mandatory argument for the `lineItemService` you just gave it `networkId`. I would be more helpful if you provide sample test case for your above method.

Comment: About `session`, it is not passed into the `getLineItem()` method, so I did not pass it into `getLineItemServiceForNetwork()`.  That does not mean it's not used - but you don't need to know about it in `getLineItem()`, which should not be responsible for setting up the ``lineItemService`.

Comment: `session` I have set as the instance property. For more info you can look into the complete example [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-java-lib/blob/master/examples/dfp_axis/src/main/java/dfp/axis/v201511/lineitemservice/GetAllLineItems.java).

Comment: About providing a sample test case, I described in my answer what the "normal usage" test should do (you may need other tests for handling empty results or bad inputs).  Not knowing the details of your 3rd-party libraries or even the name of your class under test, it's a bit tricky to write the exact test code.

Comment: I edited to add a sample test method which assumes a little further refactoring of the method under test.

Comment: What should I put in `LIST_WITH_EXPECTED_LINE_ITEM` as `LineItem` itself is a third party object and whose value depends on the `Query` passed.

Comment: For the purpose of this test, you do not care what the 3rd-party code will do (that's why you're using mocks). You just verify that you,call your service API with the correct arguments and assume the service API will do the right thing (or the wrong thing - but that's a different test).  The expected item could be nonsense - you just need to verify that the mock returns the list and your method extracts the first item from the list. To verify that the 3rd-party API returns the right thing, you need to add an integration test focused on your service API implementation which does not mock it.

Comment: "you just need to verify that the mock returns the list and your method extracts the first item from the list" what should be in that list? my mocked object or some dummy value objects?

Comment: It should be an instance of LineItem - a constant.  It can be a dummy. You just need to verify that the first object in the list that your mock service returns is the same object that is returned by `getLineItem()`.